# do "temporary" rider's carry over to final divorce agreements when the whole agreement is carried over

Tags: divorce

When my ex an I got divorce I agreed to a clause and specifically put "during the temporary period" to ensure that it expired. We went to the final hearing and carried over all provisions from the temporary agreement without discussing this one. She is now arguing that it is still valid about a year after the final agreement was signed(Aug '18).

We are going to court tomorrow to discuss before a judge...just wondering what the consensus here is

Comment: Does the clause "during the temporary period" also appear in the final order? If so it will probably not be in effect since you are not in the temporary period anymore.

Comment: @RonBeyer the question says they carried it over.

Comment: @RonBeyer it is not. the final agreement just say " all terms of the parties agreement are incorporated herin as the Final Order on Parent RIghts and Responsibilities, and Parent Child Contact"

Answer (score 1):

If it is in the temporary agreement and was carried over to the final order, it is in effect. You should have spoken up at the final hearing, but you can tell the judge you want to change it.

Comment: if they just whole-sale carried over everything...does that mean that they carried over the language specifying only for the temporary agreement? or are such limitations dropped?

Comment: You didn't specify only for the temporary agreement.  You said during it then you didn't object when it was carried over.